# What is intuitive perception of $T_{\alpha_1} \circ T_{\alpha_2} \circ ... \circ T_{\alpha_M} $ in graph domain?

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, signal-analysis, data-analysis

if $G(V,E,W)$  be a weighted graph and $\vert V \vert =N $. for any vertex $i \in \lbrace 1,2,...,,N \rbrace $ define a generalized translation operator $T_i:\mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}^N $via generalized convolution with a delta centered at vertex i:

$$(T_{i}f)(n) := \sqrt{N}(f*\delta_{i})(n) = \sqrt{N}\sum_{\ell=0}^{N-1}\hat{f}(\lambda_{\ell}) \chi^{*}_{\ell}(i)\chi_{\ell}(n) .$$
[[link]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.5708)

the set of translation operators ${T_i} \in \lbrace 1,2,...,N\rbrace $ do not form a mathematical group; i.e.,
$ T_iT_j \neq T_{i+j}.$

unlike the classical translation operator, since The translation defined above is a kernelized operator. **I don't have the intuitive perception of  $T_iT_j$ in graph domain.** And also In generally: 
$$T_{\alpha_1} \circ T_{\alpha_2} \circ ...  \circ  T_{\alpha_M} $$
[[link]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.05867)